# hybrid app runtime error in visual studio 2015

Tags: cordova, visual-studio-2015, android-emulator, apache-cordova

I am using visual studio 2015 in windows 8. I am developing hybrid app with Apache Cordova. I created a sample project when I run through ripple it is running smooth but when I use google android emulator I encounter the following statements and it is followed by errors.

```
Error statements


 1>------ Build started: Project: nidhinhybrid, Configuration: Debug Android ------
1>  ------ Ensuring correct global installation of package from source package directory: E:\VISUAL STUDIO SETUP\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\APACHECORDOVATOOLS\packages\vs-tac
1>  ------ Name from source package.json: vs-tac
1>  ------ Version from source package.json: 1.0.42
1>  ------ Package already installed globally at correct version.
1>  ------ Cordova tools 6.1.1 already installed.
1>  ------ Build Settings:
1>  ------ Build Settings:
1>  ------    platformConfigurationBldDir: C:\Users\gopus\documents\visual studio 2015\crossplatform\nidhinhybrid\nidhinhybrid\bld\Android\Debug
1>  ------    platformConfigurationBinDir: C:\Users\gopus\documents\visual studio 2015\crossplatform\nidhinhybrid\nidhinhybrid\bin\Android\Debug
1>  ------    buildCommand: build
1>  ------    platform: Android
1>  ------    cordovaPlatform: android
1>  ------    configuration: Debug
1>  ------    cordovaConfiguration: Debug
1>  ------    projectName: nidhinhybrid
1>  ------    projectSourceDir: C:\Users\gopus\documents\visual studio 2015\crossplatform\nidhinhybrid\nidhinhybrid
1>  ------    npmInstallDir: C:\Users\gopus\AppData\Roaming\npm
1>  ------    gradleProxy: http://127.0.0.1:8888/
1>  ------    buildTarget: AndroidEmulator
1>  ------    language: en-US
1>  ------ Platform android already exists
1>  ------ Copying native files from C:\Users\gopus\documents\visual studio 2015\crossplatform\nidhinhybrid\nidhinhybrid\res\native\android to platforms\android
1>  ------ Done copying native files to platforms\android
1>  ------ Updating plugins
1>  ------ Currently installed plugins: cordova-plugin-whitelist@1.2.2
1>  ------ Currently installed dependent plugins:
1>  ------ Currently configured plugins:
1>  ------ Preparing platform: android
1>  Executing "before_prepare"  hook for all plugins.
1>  Executing "before_build"  hook for all plugins.
1>  Searching PlatformJson files for differences between project vs. platform installed plugins
1>  No differences found between project and android platform. Continuing...
1>  Generating config.xml from defaults for platform "android"
1>  Found "merges" for android platform. Copying over existing "www" files.
1>  Wrote out Android application name to "nidhinhybrid"
1>  Wrote out Android package name to "io.cordova.myappb16ca2"
1>  Deleted C:\Users\gopus\documents\visual studio 2015\crossplatform\nidhinhybrid\nidhinhybrid\platforms\android\res\drawable-hdpi\icon.png
1>  Deleted C:\Users\gopus\documents\visual studio 2015\crossplatform\nidhinhybrid\nidhinhybrid\platforms\android\res\drawable-land-hdpi\icon.png
1>  Deleted C:\Users\gopus\documents\visual studio 2015\crossplatform\nidhinhybrid\nidhinhybrid\platforms\android\res\drawable-land-ldpi\icon.png
1>  Deleted C:\Users\gopus\documents\visual studio 2015\crossplatform\nidhinhybrid\nidhinhybrid\platforms\android\res\drawable-land-mdpi\icon.png
1>  Deleted C:\Users\gopus\documents\visual studio 2015\crossplatform\nidhinhybrid\nidhinhybrid\platforms\android\res\drawable-land-xhdpi\icon.png
1>  Deleted C:\Users\gopus\documents\visual studio 2015\crossplatform\nidhinhybrid\nidhinhybrid\platforms\android\res\drawable-ldpi\icon.png
1>  Deleted C:\Users\gopus\documents\visual studio 2015\crossplatform\nidhinhybrid\nidhinhybrid\platforms\android\res\drawable-mdpi\icon.png
1>  Deleted C:\Users\gopus\documents\visual studio 2015\crossplatform\nidhinhybrid\nidhinhybrid\platforms\android\res\drawable-port-hdpi\icon.png
1>  Deleted C:\Users\gopus\documents\visual studio 2015\crossplatform\nidhinhybrid\nidhinhybrid\platforms\android\res\drawable-port-ldpi\icon.png
1>  Deleted C:\Users\gopus\documents\visual studio 2015\crossplatform\nidhinhybrid\nidhinhybrid\platforms\android\res\drawable-port-mdpi\icon.png
1>  Deleted C:\Users\gopus\documents\visual studio 2015\crossplatform\nidhinhybrid\nidhinhybrid\platforms\android\res\drawable-port-xhdpi\icon.png
1>  Deleted C:\Users\gopus\documents\visual studio 2015\crossplatform\nidhinhybrid\nidhinhybrid\platforms\android\res\drawable-xhdpi\icon.png
1>  copying image from C:\Users\gopus\documents\visual studio 2015\crossplatform\nidhinhybrid\nidhinhybrid\res\icons\android\icon-36-ldpi.png to C:\Users\gopus\documents\visual studio 2015\crossplatform\nidhinhybrid\nidhinhybrid\platforms\android\res\drawable-ldpi\icon.png
1>  copying image from C:\Users\gopus\documents\visual studio 2015\crossplatform\nidhinhybrid\nidhinhybrid\res\icons\android\icon-48-mdpi.png to C:\Users\gopus\documents\visual studio 2015\crossplatform\nidhinhybrid\nidhinhybrid\platforms\android\res\drawable-mdpi\icon.png
1>  copying image from C:\Users\gopus\documents\visual studio 2015\crossplatform\nidhinhybrid\nidhinhybrid\res\icons\android\icon-72-hdpi.png to C:\Users\gopus\documents\visual studio 2015\crossplatform\nidhinhybrid\nidhinhybrid\platforms\android\res\drawable-hdpi\icon.png
1>  copying image from C:\Users\gopus\documents\visual studio 2015\crossplatform\nidhinhybrid\nidhinhybrid\res\icons\android\icon-96-xhdpi.png to C:\Users\gopus\documents\visual studio 2015\crossplatform\nidhinhybrid\nidhinhybrid\platforms\android\res\drawable-xhdpi\icon.png
1>  Deleted C:\Users\gopus\documents\visual studio 2015\crossplatform\nidhinhybrid\nidhinhybrid\platforms\android\res\drawable-hdpi\screen.png
1>  Deleted C:\Users\gopus\documents\visual studio 2015\crossplatform\nidhinhybrid\nidhinhybrid\platforms\android\res\drawable-land-hdpi\screen.png
1>  Deleted C:\Users\gopus\documents\visual studio 2015\crossplatform\nidhinhybrid\nidhinhybrid\platforms\android\res\drawable-land-ldpi\screen.png
1>  Deleted C:\Users\gopus\documents\visual studio 2015\crossplatform\nidhinhybrid\nidhinhybrid\platforms\android\res\drawable-land-mdpi\screen.png
1>  Deleted C:\Users\gopus\documents\visual studio 2015\crossplatform\nidhinhybrid\nidhinhybrid\platforms\android\res\drawable-land-xhdpi\screen.png
1>  Deleted C:\Users\gopus\documents\visual studio 2015\crossplatform\nidhinhybrid\nidhinhybrid\platforms\android\res\drawable-ldpi\screen.png
1>  Deleted C:\Users\gopus\documents\visual studio 2015\crossplatform\nidhinhybrid\nidhinhybrid\platforms\android\res\drawable-mdpi\screen.png
1>  Deleted C:\Users\gopus\documents\visual studio 2015\crossplatform\nidhinhybrid\nidhinhybrid\platforms\android\res\drawable-port-hdpi\screen.png
1>  Deleted C:\Users\gopus\documents\visual studio 2015\crossplatform\nidhinhybrid\nidhinhybrid\platforms\android\res\drawable-port-ldpi\screen.png
1>  Deleted C:\Users\gopus\documents\visual studio 2015\crossplatform\nidhinhybrid\nidhinhybrid\platforms\android\res\drawable-port-mdpi\screen.png
1>  Deleted C:\Users\gopus\documents\visual studio 2015\crossplatform\nidhinhybrid\nidhinhybrid\platforms\android\res\drawable-port-xhdpi\screen.png
1>  Deleted C:\Users\gopus\documents\visual studio 2015\crossplatform\nidhinhybrid\nidhinhybrid\platforms\android\res\drawable-xhdpi\screen.png
1>  splash screens: [{"src":"res/screens/android/screen-hdpi-landscape.png","density":"land-hdpi","platform":"android"},{"src":"res/screens/android/screen-ldpi-landscape.png","density":"land-ldpi","platform":"android"},{"src":"res/screens/android/screen-mdpi-landscape.png","density":"land-mdpi","platform":"android"},{"src":"res/screens/android/screen-xhdpi-landscape.png","density":"land-xhdpi","platform":"android"},{"src":"res/screens/android/screen-hdpi-portrait.png","density":"port-hdpi","platform":"android"},{"src":"res/screens/android/screen-ldpi-portrait.png","density":"port-ldpi","platform":"android"},{"src":"res/screens/android/screen-mdpi-portrait.png","density":"port-mdpi","platform":"android"},{"src":"res/screens/android/screen-xhdpi-portrait.png","density":"port-xhdpi","platform":"android"}]
1>  copying image from C:\Users\gopus\documents\visual studio 2015\crossplatform\nidhinhybrid\nidhinhybrid\res\screens\android\screen-hdpi-landscape.png to C:\Users\gopus\documents\visual studio 2015\crossplatform\nidhinhybrid\nidhinhybrid\platforms\android\res\drawable-land-hdpi\screen.png
1>  copying image from C:\Users\gopus\documents\visual studio 2015\crossplatform\nidhinhybrid\nidhinhybrid\res\screens\android\screen-ldpi-landscape.png to C:\Users\gopus\documents\visual studio 2015\crossplatform\nidhinhybrid\nidhinhybrid\platforms\android\res\drawable-land-ldpi\screen.png
1>  copying image from C:\Users\gopus\documents\visual studio 2015\crossplatform\nidhinhybrid\nidhinhybrid\res\screens\android\screen-mdpi-landscape.png to C:\Users\gopus\documents\visual studio 2015\crossplatform\nidhinhybrid\nidhinhybrid\platforms\android\res\drawable-land-mdpi\screen.png
1>  copying image from C:\Users\gopus\documents\visual studio 2015\crossplatform\nidhinhybrid\nidhinhybrid\res\screens\android\screen-xhdpi-landscape.png to C:\Users\gopus\documents\visual studio 2015\crossplatform\nidhinhybrid\nidhinhybrid\platforms\android\res\drawable-land-xhdpi\screen.png
1>  copying image from C:\Users\gopus\documents\visual studio 2015\crossplatform\nidhinhybrid\nidhinhybrid\res\screens\android\screen-hdpi-portrait.png to C:\Users\gopus\documents\visual studio 2015\crossplatform\nidhinhybrid\nidhinhybrid\platforms\android\res\drawable-port-hdpi\screen.png
1>  copying image from C:\Users\gopus\documents\visual studio 2015\crossplatform\nidhinhybrid\nidhinhybrid\res\screens\android\screen-ldpi-portrait.png to C:\Users\gopus\documents\visual studio 2015\crossplatform\nidhinhybrid\nidhinhybrid\platforms\android\res\drawable-port-ldpi\screen.png
1>  copying image from C:\Users\gopus\documents\visual studio 2015\crossplatform\nidhinhybrid\nidhinhybrid\res\screens\android\screen-mdpi-portrait.png to C:\Users\gopus\documents\visual studio 2015\crossplatform\nidhinhybrid\nidhinhybrid\platforms\android\res\drawable-port-mdpi\screen.png
1>  copying image from C:\Users\gopus\documents\visual studio 2015\crossplatform\nidhinhybrid\nidhinhybrid\res\screens\android\screen-xhdpi-portrait.png to C:\Users\gopus\documents\visual studio 2015\crossplatform\nidhinhybrid\nidhinhybrid\platforms\android\res\drawable-port-xhdpi\screen.png
1>  updated project successfully
1>  Executing "after_prepare"  hook for all plugins.
1>  ------ Copied C:\Users\gopus\documents\visual studio 2015\crossplatform\nidhinhybrid\nidhinhybrid\bin\Android\Debug\VSBuildInfo.xml to platforms\android\assets\www\VSBuildInfo.xml
1>  ------ Building platform: android
1>  Debug
1>  ------ Build configuration options: --debug
1>  Executing "before_compile"  hook for all plugins.
1>  ANDROID_HOME=C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk
1>  JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_79
1>  Reading build config file: C:\Users\gopus\documents\visual studio 2015\crossplatform\nidhinhybrid\nidhinhybrid\build.json
1>
1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error : FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
1>  FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
1>
1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error : * Where:
1>  * Where:
1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error : Build file 'C:\Users\gopus\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\crossplatform\nidhinhybrid\nidhinhybrid\platforms\android\build.gradle' line: 38
1>  Build file 'C:\Users\gopus\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\crossplatform\nidhinhybrid\nidhinhybrid\platforms\android\build.gradle' line: 38
1>
1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error : * What went wrong:
1>  * What went wrong:
1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error : A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'.
1>  A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'.
1>
1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error : > Could not find method mavenCentral() for arguments [] on org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler_Decorated@659125.
1>  > Could not find method mavenCentral() for arguments [] on org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler_Decorated@659125.
1>
1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error : * Try:
1>  * Try:
1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error : Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
1>  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
1>  BUILD FAILED
1>
1>  Total time: 0.869 secs
1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error : Error code 1 for command: cmd with args: /s,/c,""C:\Users\gopus\documents\visual studio 2015\crossplatform\nidhinhybrid\nidhinhybrid\platforms\android\gradlew" cdvBuildDebug -b "C:\Users\gopus\documents\visual studio 2015\crossplatform\nidhinhybrid\nidhinhybrid\platforms\android\build.gradle" -Dorg.gradle.daemon=true -Pandroid.useDeprecatedNdk=true"
1>  Error code 1 for command: cmd with args: /s,/c,""C:\Users\gopus\documents\visual studio 2015\crossplatform\nidhinhybrid\nidhinhybrid\platforms\android\gradlew" cdvBuildDebug -b "C:\Users\gopus\documents\visual studio 2015\crossplatform\nidhinhybrid\nidhinhybrid\platforms\android\build.gradle" -Dorg.gradle.daemon=true -Pandroid.useDeprecatedNdk=true"
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
========== Deploy: 0 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========


Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       Build file 'C:\Users\gopus\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\crossplatform\nidhinhybrid\nidhinhybrid\platforms\android\build.gradle' line: 38    nidhinhybrid        1   
Error       FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.    nidhinhybrid        1   
Error       * Where:    nidhinhybrid        1   
Error       * What went wrong:  nidhinhybrid        1   
Error       A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'.   nidhinhybrid        1   
Error       > Could not find method mavenCentral() for arguments [] on org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler_Decorated@1bbdfdd.   nidhinhybrid        1   
Error       * Try:  nidhinhybrid        1   
Error       Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.  nidhinhybrid        1   
Error       Error code 1 for command: cmd with args: /s,/c,""C:\Users\gopus\documents\visual studio 2015\crossplatform\nidhinhybrid\nidhinhybrid\platforms\android\gradlew" cdvBuildDebug -b "C:\Users\gopus\documents\visual studio 2015\crossplatform\nidhinhybrid\nidhinhybrid\platforms\android\build.gradle" -Dorg.gradle.daemon=true -Pandroid.useDeprecatedNdk=true" nidhinhybrid
```

1

when I am running in ripple nexus (galaxy). the app is running perfectly but when I run through google android emulator these errors shown so please help me to solve the problem. I think error is it id not downloading gradle file from maven.

Comment: I suggest you to use phonegap to create application because i also had faced this issue .

Comment: hi friend i know how to use phonegap and also develop app . i need to develop a hybrid app in visual studio 2015 .for that i post this error.very bad comment.if there is a problem there will be a solution.

Comment: `A system proxy has been detected, but gradle is not currently configured to use it. Writing a gradle.properties file into platforms/android with the detected proxy settings.` this message gives the solution. By writing a `gradle.properties` file, you can refer to [this document](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_environment.html).

Comment: Elvis  thank u for always helping me. i referred above document  but i dint understand how to set Gradle .properties.can u please specific how can i solve this

Comment: my current gradle.property file contain  following   so i want to know what change i want to make            systemProp.http.proxyHost=127.0.0.1
systemProp.http.proxyPort=8080
systemProp.https.proxyHost=127.0.0.1
systemProp.https.proxyPort=8080

Comment: Elvis i attached all details in this question  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38587327/visual-studio-2015-apache-cordova-build-error  so please refer.i tried many solution but none of the works and help me to solve the problem