# Visual Studio 2015 - Apache Cordova Build Error

Tags: android, visual-studio-2015, build.gradle, apache-cordova

I am using visual studio 2015 in windows 8. I created a hybrid app when i tried to build the project i get following error .am running in vs android emulator kitkat 5.5" .but when i am running in ripple it is working sometime.so please refer following error and help me to solve the problem.

```
  1>------ Build started: Project: nidhinhybrid, Configuration: Debug Android ------
    1>  ------ Ensuring correct global installation of package from source package directory: E:\VISUAL STUDIO SETUP\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\APACHECORDOVATOOLS\packages\vs-tac
    1>  ------ Name from source package.json: vs-tac
    1>  ------ Version from source package.json: 1.0.42
    1>  ------ Package already installed globally at correct version.
    1>  ------ Cordova tools 6.1.1 already installed.
    1>  ------ Build Settings:
    1>  ------ Build Settings:
    1>  ------    platformConfigurationBldDir: C:\Users\gopus\documents\visual studio 2015\crossplatform\nidhinhybrid\nidhinhybrid\bld\Android\Debug
    1>  ------    platformConfigurationBinDir: C:\Users\gopus\documents\visual studio 2015\crossplatform\nidhinhybrid\nidhinhybrid\bin\Android\Debug
    1>  ------    buildCommand: build
    1>  ------    platform: Android
    1>  ------    cordovaPlatform: android
    1>  ------    configuration: Debug
    1>  ------    cordovaConfiguration: Debug
    1>  ------    projectName: nidhinhybrid
    1>  ------    projectSourceDir: C:\Users\gopus\documents\visual studio 2015\crossplatform\nidhinhybrid\nidhinhybrid
    1>  ------    npmInstallDir: C:\Users\gopus\AppData\Roaming\npm
    1>  ------    gradleProxy: http://127.0.0.1:8888/
    1>  ------    buildTarget: AndroidEmulator
    1>  ------    language: en-US
    1>  ------ Platform android already exists
    1>  ------ Copying native files from C:\Users\gopus\documents\visual studio 2015\crossplatform\nidhinhybrid\nidhinhybrid\res\native\android to platforms\android
    1>  ------ Done copying native files to platforms\android
    1>  ------ Updating plugins
    1>  ------ Currently installed plugins: cordova-plugin-whitelist@1.2.2
    1>  ------ Currently installed dependent plugins:
    1>  ------ Currently configured plugins:
    1>  ------ Preparing platform: android
    1>  Executing "before_prepare"  hook for all plugins.
    1>  Executing "before_build"  hook for all plugins.
    1>  Searching PlatformJson files for differences between project vs. platform installed plugins
    1>  No differences found between project and android platform. Continuing...
    1>  Generating config.xml from defaults for platform "android"
    1>  Found "merges" for android platform. Copying over existing "www" files.
    1>  Wrote out Android application name to "nidhinhybrid"
    1>  Wrote out Android package name to "io.cordova.myappb16ca2"
    1>  Deleted C:\Users\gopus\documents\visual studio 2015\crossplatform\nidhinhybrid\nidhinhybrid\platforms\android\res\drawable-hdpi\icon.png
    1>  Deleted C:\Users\gopus\documents\visual studio 2015\crossplatform\nidhinhybrid\nidhinhybrid\platforms\android\res\drawable-land-hdpi\icon.png
    1>  Deleted C:\Users\gopus\documents\visual studio 2015\crossplatform\nidhinhybrid\nidhinhybrid\platforms\android\res\drawable-land-ldpi\icon.png
    1>  Deleted C:\Users\gopus\documents\visual studio 2015\crossplatform\nidhinhybrid\nidhinhybrid\platforms\android\res\drawable-land-mdpi\icon.png
    1>  Deleted C:\Users\gopus\documents\visual studio 2015\crossplatform\nidhinhybrid\nidhinhybrid\platforms\android\res\drawable-land-xhdpi\icon.png
    1>  Deleted C:\Users\gopus\documents\visual studio 2015\crossplatform\nidhinhybrid\nidhinhybrid\platforms\android\res\drawable-ldpi\icon.png
    1>  Deleted C:\Users\gopus\documents\visual studio 2015\crossplatform\nidhinhybrid\nidhinhybrid\platforms\android\res\drawable-mdpi\icon.png
    1>  Deleted C:\Users\gopus\documents\visual studio 2015\crossplatform\nidhinhybrid\nidhinhybrid\platforms\android\res\drawable-port-hdpi\icon.png
    1>  Deleted C:\Users\gopus\documents\visual studio 2015\crossplatform\nidhinhybrid\nidhinhybrid\platforms\android\res\drawable-port-ldpi\icon.png
    1>  Deleted C:\Users\gopus\documents\visual studio 2015\crossplatform\nidhinhybrid\nidhinhybrid\platforms\android\res\drawable-port-mdpi\icon.png
    1>  Deleted C:\Users\gopus\documents\visual studio 2015\crossplatform\nidhinhybrid\nidhinhybrid\platforms\android\res\drawable-port-xhdpi\icon.png
    1>  Deleted C:\Users\gopus\documents\visual studio 2015\crossplatform\nidhinhybrid\nidhinhybrid\platforms\android\res\drawable-xhdpi\icon.png
    1>  copying image from C:\Users\gopus\documents\visual studio 2015\crossplatform\nidhinhybrid\nidhinhybrid\res\icons\android\icon-36-ldpi.png to C:\Users\gopus\documents\visual studio 2015\crossplatform\nidhinhybrid\nidhinhybrid\platforms\android\res\drawable-ldpi\icon.png
    1>  copying image from C:\Users\gopus\documents\visual studio 2015\crossplatform\nidhinhybrid\nidhinhybrid\res\icons\android\icon-48-mdpi.png to C:\Users\gopus\documents\visual studio 2015\crossplatform\nidhinhybrid\nidhinhybrid\platforms\android\res\drawable-mdpi\icon.png
    1>  copying image from C:\Users\gopus\documents\visual studio 2015\crossplatform\nidhinhybrid\nidhinhybrid\res\icons\android\icon-72-hdpi.png to C:\Users\gopus\documents\visual studio 2015\crossplatform\nidhinhybrid\nidhinhybrid\platforms\android\res\drawable-hdpi\icon.png
    1>  copying image from C:\Users\gopus\documents\visual studio 2015\crossplatform\nidhinhybrid\nidhinhybrid\res\icons\android\icon-96-xhdpi.png to C:\Users\gopus\documents\visual studio 2015\crossplatform\nidhinhybrid\nidhinhybrid\platforms\android\res\drawable-xhdpi\icon.png
    1>  Deleted C:\Users\gopus\documents\visual studio 2015\crossplatform\nidhinhybrid\nidhinhybrid\platforms\android\res\drawable-hdpi\screen.png
    1>  Deleted C:\Users\gopus\documents\visual studio 2015\crossplatform\nidhinhybrid\nidhinhybrid\platforms\android\res\drawable-land-hdpi\screen.png
    1>  Deleted C:\Users\gopus\documents\visual studio 2015\crossplatform\nidhinhybrid\nidhinhybrid\platforms\android\res\drawable-land-ldpi\screen.png
    1>  Deleted C:\Users\gopus\documents\visual studio 2015\crossplatform\nidhinhybrid\nidhinhybrid\platforms\android\res\drawable-land-mdpi\screen.png
    1>  Deleted C:\Users\gopus\documents\visual studio 2015\crossplatform\nidhinhybrid\nidhinhybrid\platforms\android\res\drawable-land-xhdpi\screen.png
    1>  Deleted C:\Users\gopus\documents\visual studio 2015\crossplatform\nidhinhybrid\nidhinhybrid\platforms\android\res\drawable-ldpi\screen.png
    1>  Deleted C:\Users\gopus\documents\visual studio 2015\crossplatform\nidhinhybrid\nidhinhybrid\platforms\android\res\drawable-mdpi\screen.png
    1>  Deleted C:\Users\gopus\documents\visual studio 2015\crossplatform\nidhinhybrid\nidhinhybrid\platforms\android\res\drawable-port-hdpi\screen.png
    1>  Deleted C:\Users\gopus\documents\visual studio 2015\crossplatform\nidhinhybrid\nidhinhybrid\platforms\android\res\drawable-port-ldpi\screen.png
    1>  Deleted C:\Users\gopus\documents\visual studio 2015\crossplatform\nidhinhybrid\nidhinhybrid\platforms\android\res\drawable-port-mdpi\screen.png
    1>  Deleted C:\Users\gopus\documents\visual studio 2015\crossplatform\nidhinhybrid\nidhinhybrid\platforms\android\res\drawable-port-xhdpi\screen.png
    1>  Deleted C:\Users\gopus\documents\visual studio 2015\crossplatform\nidhinhybrid\nidhinhybrid\platforms\android\res\drawable-xhdpi\screen.png
    1>  splash screens: [{"src":"res/screens/android/screen-hdpi-landscape.png","density":"land-hdpi","platform":"android"},{"src":"res/screens/android/screen-ldpi-landscape.png","density":"land-ldpi","platform":"android"},{"src":"res/screens/android/screen-mdpi-landscape.png","density":"land-mdpi","platform":"android"},{"src":"res/screens/android/screen-xhdpi-landscape.png","density":"land-xhdpi","platform":"android"},{"src":"res/screens/android/screen-hdpi-portrait.png","density":"port-hdpi","platform":"android"},{"src":"res/screens/android/screen-ldpi-portrait.png","density":"port-ldpi","platform":"android"},{"src":"res/screens/android/screen-mdpi-portrait.png","density":"port-mdpi","platform":"android"},{"src":"res/screens/android/screen-xhdpi-portrait.png","density":"port-xhdpi","platform":"android"}]
    1>  copying image from C:\Users\gopus\documents\visual studio 2015\crossplatform\nidhinhybrid\nidhinhybrid\res\screens\android\screen-hdpi-landscape.png to C:\Users\gopus\documents\visual studio 2015\crossplatform\nidhinhybrid\nidhinhybrid\platforms\android\res\drawable-land-hdpi\screen.png
    1>  copying image from C:\Users\gopus\documents\visual studio 2015\crossplatform\nidhinhybrid\nidhinhybrid\res\screens\android\screen-ldpi-landscape.png to C:\Users\gopus\documents\visual studio 2015\crossplatform\nidhinhybrid\nidhinhybrid\platforms\android\res\drawable-land-ldpi\screen.png
    1>  copying image from C:\Users\gopus\documents\visual studio 2015\crossplatform\nidhinhybrid\nidhinhybrid\res\screens\android\screen-mdpi-landscape.png to C:\Users\gopus\documents\visual studio 2015\crossplatform\nidhinhybrid\nidhinhybrid\platforms\android\res\drawable-land-mdpi\screen.png
    1>  copying image from C:\Users\gopus\documents\visual studio 2015\crossplatform\nidhinhybrid\nidhinhybrid\res\screens\android\screen-xhdpi-landscape.png to C:\Users\gopus\documents\visual studio 2015\crossplatform\nidhinhybrid\nidhinhybrid\platforms\android\res\drawable-land-xhdpi\screen.png
    1>  copying image from C:\Users\gopus\documents\visual studio 2015\crossplatform\nidhinhybrid\nidhinhybrid\res\screens\android\screen-hdpi-portrait.png to C:\Users\gopus\documents\visual studio 2015\crossplatform\nidhinhybrid\nidhinhybrid\platforms\android\res\drawable-port-hdpi\screen.png
    1>  copying image from C:\Users\gopus\documents\visual studio 2015\crossplatform\nidhinhybrid\nidhinhybrid\res\screens\android\screen-ldpi-portrait.png to C:\Users\gopus\documents\visual studio 2015\crossplatform\nidhinhybrid\nidhinhybrid\platforms\android\res\drawable-port-ldpi\screen.png
    1>  copying image from C:\Users\gopus\documents\visual studio 2015\crossplatform\nidhinhybrid\nidhinhybrid\res\screens\android\screen-mdpi-portrait.png to C:\Users\gopus\documents\visual studio 2015\crossplatform\nidhinhybrid\nidhinhybrid\platforms\android\res\drawable-port-mdpi\screen.png
    1>  copying image from C:\Users\gopus\documents\visual studio 2015\crossplatform\nidhinhybrid\nidhinhybrid\res\screens\android\screen-xhdpi-portrait.png to C:\Users\gopus\documents\visual studio 2015\crossplatform\nidhinhybrid\nidhinhybrid\platforms\android\res\drawable-port-xhdpi\screen.png
    1>  updated project successfully
    1>  Executing "after_prepare"  hook for all plugins.
    1>  ------ Copied C:\Users\gopus\documents\visual studio 2015\crossplatform\nidhinhybrid\nidhinhybrid\bin\Android\Debug\VSBuildInfo.xml to platforms\android\assets\www\VSBuildInfo.xml
    1>  ------ Building platform: android
    1>  Debug
    1>  ------ Build configuration options: --debug
    1>  Executing "before_compile"  hook for all plugins.
    1>  ANDROID_HOME=C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk
    1>  JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_79
    1>  Reading build config file: C:\Users\gopus\documents\visual studio 2015\crossplatform\nidhinhybrid\nidhinhybrid\build.json
    1>
    1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error : FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
    1>  FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
    1>
    1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error : * What went wrong:
    1>  * What went wrong:
    1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error : A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
    1>  A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
    1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error : > Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':classpath'.
    1>  > Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':classpath'.
    1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error :  > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0.
    1>     > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0.
    1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error :  Required by:
    1>       Required by:
    1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error :  :android:unspecified
    1>           :android:unspecified
    1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error :  > Could not HEAD 'https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/1.5.0/gradle-1.5.0.pom'.
    1>        > Could not HEAD 'https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/1.5.0/gradle-1.5.0.pom'.
    1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error :  > peer not authenticated
    1>           > peer not authenticated
    1>
    1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error : * Try:
    1>  * Try:
    1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error : Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
    1>  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
    1>
    1>  BUILD FAILED
    1>
    1>  Total time: 1.073 secs
    1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error : Error code 1 for command: cmd with args: /s,/c,""C:\Users\gopus\documents\visual studio 2015\crossplatform\nidhinhybrid\nidhinhybrid\platforms\android\gradlew" cdvBuildDebug -b "C:\Users\gopus\documents\visual studio 2015\crossplatform\nidhinhybrid\nidhinhybrid\platforms\android\build.gradle" -Dorg.gradle.daemon=true -Pandroid.useDeprecatedNdk=true"
    1>  Error code 1 for command: cmd with args: /s,/c,""C:\Users\gopus\documents\visual studio 2015\crossplatform\nidhinhybrid\nidhinhybrid\platforms\android\gradlew" cdvBuildDebug -b "C:\Users\gopus\documents\visual studio 2015\crossplatform\nidhinhybrid\nidhinhybrid\platforms\android\build.gradle" -Dorg.gradle.daemon=true -Pandroid.useDeprecatedNdk=true"
    ========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
    ========== Deploy: 0 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========

      Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
    Error       > Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':classpath'.    nidhinhybrid        1   
    Error       FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.    nidhinhybrid        1   
    Error       * What went wrong:  nidhinhybrid        1   
    Error       A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.  nidhinhybrid        1   
    Error        > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0.  nidhinhybrid        1   
    Error        Required by:   nidhinhybrid        1   
    Error        :android:unspecified   nidhinhybrid        1   
    Error        > Could not HEAD 'https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/1.5.0/gradle-1.5.0.pom'.   nidhinhybrid        1   
    Error        > peer not authenticated   nidhinhybrid        1   
    Error       * Try:  nidhinhybrid        1   
    Error       Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.  nidhinhybrid        1   
    Error       Error code 1 for command: cmd with args: /s,/c,""C:\Users\gopus\documents\visual studio 2015\crossplatform\nidhinhybrid\nidhinhybrid\platforms\android\gradlew" cdvBuildDebug -b "C:\Users\gopus\documents\visual studio 2015\crossplatform\nidhinhybrid\nidhinhybrid\platforms\android\build.gradle" -Dorg.gradle.daemon=true -Pandroid.useDeprecatedNdk=true" nidhinhybrid        1   


I am also attaching screenshots of  gradle.build file, build.jason , gradle.properties, fiddler screenshot (enabled to authenticate corporate proxy) and gradlew.bat execution screenshot.
enter image description here
[![enter image description here][1]][1]
[![enter image description here][2]][2]
[![enter image description here][3]][3]
[enter image description here][4]
[![enter image description here][5]][5]

I tried many solution but none of them works .so please help me to solve the problem.i also use fiddler and make capture traffic on but it also fail so please help me to solve the problem
```

Comment: I found a similar case [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35442715/cordova-build-could-not-resolve-com-android-tools-buildgradle1-5-0). Please try the steps of the answer.

Comment: i dnt feel both are similar.

Comment: my problem is still existing so please help me to solve the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This work for me.now project is build successfully after many tries.there is no proxy error i think there may be any error accesing maven gradle link.may be the project is not taking https links. this link is http so it is working smoothly. change the gradle.build like this inside cordovaLib and also common for project
Make this changes to the top-level build.gradle file.

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        //jcenter()
        jcenter {
            url "http://jcenter.bintray.com/" 
        }
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        //jcenter()
        jcenter {
            url "http://jcenter.bintray.com/" 
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are probably behind a corporate proxy because, gradle has failed to download to your system.

--> Could not GET 'https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/1.5.0/gradle-1.5.0.pom

Android builds packages with Gradle.

Either authentication is required or https links are blocked.

Possible Solutions:

**Fiddler** can help to allow tools to authenticate automatically ( see menu options...), you will need to point your proxy settings to fiddler and allow fiddler to act as proxy for your system.

Secondly goto the android sdk folder, search for https in config files and **change it to http**.  Normally this can help you to download the gradle package.

**Install gradle yourself**: make the download yourself (from the browser) and  unzip the contents as is  in your user directory under  .gradle\
I also added proxy settings to this folder for proxy settings:  gradle.properties with following contents:

```
systemProp.http.proxyHost=localhost
systemProp.http.proxyPort=8888
systemProp.https.proxyHost=localhost
systemProp.https.proxyPort=8888
```

Environment variable _JAVA_OPTIONS

From commandline:

```
setx  _JAVA_OPTIONS = "-Xmx512M -Dhttp.proxyHost="localhost" -Dhttp.proxyPort="8888" -Dhttps.proxyHost="localhost" -Dhttps.proxyPort="8888" -Dmaven.wagon.http.ssl.insecure=true -Dmaven.wagon.http.ssl.allowall=true"
```

The Memory constraint (-Xmx...) were also added for building these Cordova packages!

Comment: Thank u i already installed fiddler but i dnt know how to use it for my problem.if u please explain that also.it will be very much helpful...

Comment: i tried the solution u mentioned above but it dnt works.so i add some more images .so please refer the images and please help me to solve the problem

Comment: Where i want to apply this java code whatz the nxt step

Comment: Do you have the same _JAVA_OPTIONS as me now?  important to have these! See my answer at the bottom...

Comment: Sir am not a expert.in place of proxy host whether i want to put local host or my system ip? .are u saying to place these java code instead of old code in gradle.properties.

Comment: localhost or 127,0,0,1 makes no difference.  I change the answer to include how to set the variable in your system. After this you will need to  restart VS2015 to see the changes

Comment: Inside which directory in commandline i want to use this java code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118493/discussion-between-nidhin-johny-and-schwarzie2478).